# How to increase the expiry time of access token?

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

I have got access token and it expires within 1 hour but i want it to work more than that so i used setExpiresInSeconds() method to set the time and when i retrieve the value using getExpiresInSeconds(). It shows the time i added but the access token expires within 1 hour even i have kept time more than 1 hour.

GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(serviceAccount);

```
            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
              Set<String> scopes = new HashSet<String>();        
                scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
                scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP);
                scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER);

            GoogleCredential credentialWithUser = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountUser(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_USER)  // <--- mail of domain's admin
                    .setServiceAccountId(googleCred.getServiceAccountId())
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKey(googleCred.getServiceAccountPrivateKey())
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyId(googleCred.getServiceAccountPrivateKeyId())  
                    .setTokenServerEncodedUrl(googleCred.getTokenServerEncodedUrl()).build();                     

          // Use the Google credential to generate an access token

          credentialWithUser.refreshToken();
          credentialWithUser.setExpiresInSeconds(5000l);    
          token = credentialWithUser.getAccessToken();
          log.info("getAccessToken()  access token value  : " + token );
          String lifeSpan = credentialWithUser.getExpiresInSeconds().toString();
          log.info("getAccessToken()  access token lifespan in second  : " + lifeSpan + "sec");
```

I want my access token to have longer expiry time. I am developing desktop  application and i am not able to use url to get the refresh token because i done have redirect_uri. Can you please suggest me what would be best option to increase the time period of access token?

Answer (score 0):

From the Javadoc (my emphasis):

> ```
> public Credential setExpiresInSeconds(java.lang.Long expiresIn)
> ```
>
> Sets the lifetime in seconds of the access token (for example 3600 for an hour) or null for none.
>
> ***Overriding is only supported for the purpose of calling the super implementation and changing the return type, but nothing else.***

The access token is provided by Google to allow you to access the API. There wouldn't be much security if you could change the expiration time, would there.